# RubyOnRails classes / Preloading vs. new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

The use case is the following : some external app sends a webhook, which the rails app receive. I'm using a custom class to retarget the payload elsewhere.

This custom class pretty much always does the same thing via the same method.

The class code :

```
class Retarget
  def order_paid(params)
    # do some processing
  end
end
```

Used like so in a controller :

```
def process_webhook
  insert = Retarget.new
  data = params.except(:action, :controller)
  insert.order_paid(data)
  head :ok
end
```

My problem is the following, if I want to verify if the method is called in a request spec, it would obviously fails. Some code below :

```
it 'triggers' do
  ... some call that fire the controller action
  expect(Retarget).to receive(:order_paid).with(..matching data)
end
```

Double checking that the method is called while testing the controller  request sounds a safe check for me.

I was wondering if it could be achieved somehow. Or if things should remain tested separately — which would then let one assume the line presence in the controller (`insert.order_paid(data)`) would be enough

My Idea would be to preload at boot the class (eg. `RetargetWebhook = Retarget.new` in a `config/initializers` file), so it could be used anywhere; but I guess there would be a downfall to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you need an instance, but to be safe, lets keep it. I suggest:

```
class Retarget  
  def self.order_paid(params)
    new.order_paid(params)
  end

  def order_paid(params)
    # do some processing
  end
end
```

And use it:

```
Retarget.order_paid(params.except(:action, :controller))
```

This way `Retarget.order_paid` would create the instance itself.

Other options could lead to use singleton but I would stay away from this as there is few added value, and its potentially a path towards confusion if you rely on instance variables and you start memoizing.

Comment: My main goal is to be able to actually have a single instance (or a similar approach) I could rely on anywhere, then be able to test it as shown. This is what you're not recommending in your last paragraph ? Sorry for those questions, I have to dig further into classes/modules/etc… thx for any pointers

Comment: I would not use a single instance because it could introduce funky bugs if ever you start memoizing things (like you could/would in any normal object) + I am not sure of the added value anyway

Comment: Maybe you just dont need an instance and can handle everything as class method?

Comment: Which would be, like a private class method in the same controller ?

Comment: No, like `def self.order_paid(params)` in `Retarget` as I suggested

Comment: ok I see. if I may ask; why not a `module Retarget def self.order_paid(params) …processing code… end end` ? This is what you're explaining in the last paragraph maybe

Comment: you could definitely yes, depends whether or not you want to instantiate an object afterwards :)

Comment: humm… I guess I'll only know by trying those two ways (:. thx a lot!